# If $X$ deformation retracts to a point $x$, then each nbhd. $U$ of $x$ has a nbhd. $V \subset U$ of $x$ s.t. $V \hookrightarrow U$ is nullhomotopic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, solution-verification

This is a problem that I'm doing. Here  $V \hookrightarrow U$ is the inclusion map of $V$ in $U$.

I don't understand the point of having $V \subset U$. In the following I'm presenting a solution that seems to suggest that any neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ would already have that property. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and please keep your answer elementary as I'm trying to build things up from the basic definitions.

Let $g$ be the retraction of X onto $\{x\}$. Since $X$ deformation retracts onto $\{x\}$, there exists a homotopy $H: X \times I \to X$ such that, for all $y \in X$, $H(y,0) = id_X(y) = y$, and $H(y,1) = i_{\{x\}}(g(y)) = i_{\{x\}}(x) = x$, where $i_{\{x\}}$ is the inclusion map $\{x\} \hookrightarrow X$.

Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$ and $i_U$ be the inclusion map $U \hookrightarrow X$. Then I define the homotopy between $i_U$ and the constant map that sends $p \in U$ to $x$ as follows: $F: U \times I \to U$, $F(p,t) = i_U^{-1}(H(i_U(p),t))$. Would this map be acceptable? If no, why not?

Answer (score 1):

The question is if your $H$ is a deformation retract or a *strong* deformation retract, since if $H$ is not [*strong* deformation retract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract#Deformation_retract_and_strong_deformation_retract) it could happen that $F(i_U(p),t)) \not \in U$ for $t \neq 0,1$. Thus $i_U^{-1}(F(i_U(p),t)))$ and then also your $F$ might be not well defined.

Comment: These are the definitions that we're using. Are they sufficient for my proof to work? https://imgur.com/ITR7M5K

Comment: No, the linked definition only garantees that $H$ fixes the retract $\{x\}$ for all $t$, not a neighbourhood $U$. Thus you cannot expect that $F(i_U(p),t)) \in U$ for all $p \in U, t \in[0,1]$

Comment: I see your point, but this raises another question. My understanding of the issue is that my definition of $F$ uses $H$, whose co-domain is $X$, which is larger than $F$'s co-domain $U$. So the "path" $F$ from $p$ to $x$ might actually go "outside" $U$. But then how does having $H$ being a strong DR help? It seems to me that that added requirement would only fixes $x$, but not any $p \in U$?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification anyways. I will keep working to find another, correct homotopy and might need your help later.

Comment: sorry, I confused a point: your definition $i_A \circ g \cong id_X \text{ rel } A$ coinsides with the definition of strong DR from wiki, i.e. for all $t$ "nothing" happens with $A = \{x\}$. You are right, also strong DR in general not suffice to allow you to guarantee that $H$ maps $I \times U$ to $U$. I think that it depends concretly on the choice of $U$. For examply if $X \mathbb{R}^2, x=(0,0)$ and the homotopy $H$ contracts radially then your construction work for open ball $U_r(0)$ around $x$ with radius $r$ but if you choose

Comment: as $U$ a disjoint union of two balls where only one of them cointains $x$, then your restrction of $H$ to $U$ obviously fails; draw a picture of radial contraction.